# This leads to App crash. All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes)

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

Here is my entire build.gradle(Module:app) How to fix this? This is causing app crash. I have tried to add some more code by reading earlier/previous posts about it. But it didn't helped. 
However it lead to successful gradle sync and successful installation of app.
Vut app crashes.

`apply plugin: 'com.android.application'`

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.akash.nbrider"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
'proguard-rules.pro'
     }
}
}

dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
         androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', 
         {
              exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
         })
          compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
          // compile 'com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:25.3.1'
         compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
         compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
         compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
         /*compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.2.0'
         compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.2.0'*/
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EtHBu.png)

Comment: It looks like one of the dependencies has a transitive dependency on an older support library version. I suppose it might be the old play-services. You can run `app:depenendecies` or `app:dependencyInsight` gradle task (assuming your app module is named `app`) to check which package depends on `com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:23.0.0`

Answer (score -1):

Problem is with these two lines

```
buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"
...
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
```

They should use the same main version number. If there is v. 26 library you should use that one. Otherwise, downgrade buildToolsVersion to 25.

The easiest way to install 25 buildTools would be to just manually change to 25 in build.Gradle, Sync Gradle and you should get clickable link.

Comment: Actually it's the `compileSdkVersion` that should match the support library version.

Comment: I think relationship is compileSdkVersion >= buildToolsVersion.
And I'm pretty sure buildTools must match Library